# How do I add a category to my post_type

Tags: categories, post-type

I have a section in my dashboard called "services".

- I have 4 services
- I have 2 categories for these services: residential and commercial
- 2 of the 4 services have the category "residential", and the other 2
  "commercial"

As it is now my services page is pulling up all 4 services.

Question: What code do I add, to show only the 2 services with the category of residential?

Here is my current code on the `archive-service.php` page:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'service',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'paged' => $paged,
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
```

Comment: The [`WP_Query` Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) has a list of all query parameters with examples of how to use them.

Comment: Do I need to add a function to functions.php

Comment: From the above Codex page, I used this:

'tax_query' => array(
  array(
   'taxonomy' => 'people',
   'field'    => 'slug',
   'terms'    => 'bob',
  ),
 ),

But changed it to this:

'tax_query' => array(
  array(
   'taxonomy' => 'people',
   'field'    => 'slug',
   'terms'    => 'bob',
  ),
 ),

My final code:

'tax_query' => array(
  array(
   'taxonomy' => 'people',
   'field'    => 'slug',
   'terms'    => 'bob',
  ),
 ),

Thanks again....

Comment: Add your solution as an answer, instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your args:

```
'taxonomies' => array( 'category' )
```

Should look like this-

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'service',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the above Codex page, I used this:

`'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'people',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'bob',
        ),
    ),`

But changed it to this:

`'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'category_service',
                                'field'    => 'slug',
                                'terms'    => 'residential',
                            ),
                        ),`

My final code:

```
<?php 
            $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'service',
                'posts_per_page' => 8,
                'paged' => $paged,
                'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'category_service',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => 'residential',
                        ),
                    ),

            );
            $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
            while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
        ?>
```

Thanks again!